# Beep in InputStream / Scanner

Tags: java, inputstream, java.util.scanner, beep

I was viewing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445161/1292230) and I noticed that the delimiter was set to `\\A`, which is a beep, right? Why is a beep used in the `InputStream`? I'm still pretty fuzzy on what a beep even is (Isn't is just for a literal beep?), so I am quite confused as to why it's used as the delimiter, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\A` is the beginning of the string.  It differs from `^` in that most regex implementations `^` matches after line breaks as well, while `\A` does not.

`\a` is the bell character.

Comment: Okay. Why would that be the delimiter, though? Shouldn't it start at the `\A` anyways?

Comment: The answer you refer to uses it as a delimiter.  This allows the entire contents of the stream to be returned in a single String token, from `Scanner.next()`.

Comment: What is the default value, then? I would have figured that if a dilimiter wasn't set, that it would return the whole string anyways.

Comment: Scanner delimits on whitespace, by default, as defined by [`Character.isWhitespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char))